# How to open location settings in android using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try to open location settings in android using [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/120362/opening-location-settings-page-or-prompting-user-to-enable-location) tutorial, but in this method I don't know what to write to open location settings for the App:

```
public void OpenSettings(){ }
```

Do I need additional libraries? I wrote this code:

```
public interface ILocSettings
{
      void OpenSettings();
}

public void OpenSettings(){ }
```

In the GPS button method I write this code:

```
 var myAction = await DisplayAlert("Location", "Please Turn On Location", "OK", "CANCEL");
 if (myAction)
 {
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == global::Xamarin.Forms.Device.Android)
    {
        //DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService>().OpenSettings();
        global::Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ILocSettings>().OpenSettings();
    }
    else
    {
        _ = DisplayAlert("Device", "You are using some other shit", "YEP");
    }
 }
 else
 {
    _ = DisplayAlert("Alert", "User Denied Permission", "OK");
 }
```

The message appears, but I don't know what to write in the OpenSettings() to open GPS location settings on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package that will make opening the App settings way easier.

just write:

```
CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
```

Plugin name Plugin.Permissions :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Plugin.Permissions is deprecated so Xamarin Essentials is recommended as I shared in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Opening other Activities on Android is done through Intents. To open Location Settings you can use the ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS intent.

Something like this would probably work:

```cs
var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

If Android doesn't like the Application Context, you might need to resolve the top Activity and use that as your Context instead.

If you are using Xamarin.Essentials you can get the top activity with: `Platform.CurrentActivity`:

```cs
var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No longer works. android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS dat=package: }
 at

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately libraries do this work, so you don't need to write all the code needed to make this happen. Since Plugin.Permissions is deprecated, you can simply use the ShowSettingsUI function inside Xamarin Essentials using one line of code:

```
Xamarin.Essentials.AppInfo.ShowSettingsUI();
```

You can see more details here from [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/app-information?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#displaying-application-settings)