# Xamarin Forms/Xamarin Android Open Location Settings

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is this something new? I remember being able to open the location settings which would take me to app specific page?
There is a exact question available:[How to open location settings in android using xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735309/how-to-open-location-settings-in-android-using-xamarin)

That approach no longer works. Here is the code:

```
try
            {
                CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(new Intent(
                    Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings,
                    Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:"+ Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName)));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                OpenAppSettings();
            }
```

No matter what this always throws error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS dat=package: }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2200)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1839)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5471)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:647)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5429)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:628)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5927)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5894)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(AlertDialog_IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerImplementor.java:31)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Also,
I found this sample code from google accompanist package which seems to open it, but I could not find what that package is specifically doing to open the page:

```
bgLocationPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem in my project. But I can open the location settings with the following code:

```
var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

But I can use the following code to open the app's details settings:

```
var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings,
    Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:"+ Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

So I think there is no an activity about the special application's
Location Settings.